# table { border-collapse: separate; } or table { border-collapse: collapse; }

Tags: css, xhtml

What should i keep
`table { border-collapse: separate; }` or `table { border-collapse: collapse; }` in my css.

which would be better in which condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want. They are different ways to render a table with different visual results. Check out [this article](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/bordercollapse/1/) for an illustration.

`separate` is the default.

Support for some `border-collapse` settings is incomplete in IE. See the brilliant [compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html)

Comment: why eric meyer added `{ border-collapse: collapse; }` in his CSS reset? What's the purpose?

Comment: Half the point of a reset is to set all the spacing to 0, you couldn't do that if you left the spacing between table cells.

Comment: and is `cellspacing="0"` and `{ border-collapse: collapse; }` same thing?

Comment: BTW+1 article is very useful. gave me the new idea for table design.